# How would I go about requiring authentication to view images from my site?

Tags: .net, image, authentication, iis, web

Maybe I'm going about this wrong, but I have a .Net web application being served through IIS, and I'm trying to figure out how to get more fine-tuned permissions on images that exist on the filesystem. As of right now, if you have a link to the image, you can load it, regardless of whether or not you're logged in to the site.

My question is, what configuration settings would I be looking for to allow images to be loaded while logged in to the site, but deny permissions if the user has no sort of authentication? As an additional step, is there anything I can do to take whatever credentials the user has and use it for additional account permissions? E.g. think of the case on facebook where user A is friends with user B and not user C, user B shouldn't be able to share links to user A's pictures with user C, and none of the users should be able to load that link if they're not logged into their accounts.

Any pointers on which configurations to look at?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IIS Authentication Methods".

Example,if you are Hosting website www.example.com and the images are served from "C:/www.example.com/images" folder.Expand the website in the IIS,click on the "images" directory.In the feature view, open "Authentication" feature which must be like below

[image]

Disable the Anonymous Authentication and Enable Windows Authentication.Make sure the changes are set to child directory only.

Now the users must prompt for Windows Authentication to access the images.